# Converting this code from R to Shell script?

Tags: r, shell, unit-testing, csv

So I'm running a program that works but the issue is my computer is not powerful enough to handle the task. I have a code written in R but I have access to a supercomputer that runs a  Unix system (as one would expect).

The program is designed to read a .csv file and find everything with the unit ft3(monthly total) in the "Units" column and select the value in the column before it. The files are charts that list things in multiple units.

To convert this program in R:

```
getwd()
setwd("/Users/youruserName/Desktop")
myData= read.table("yourFileName.csv", header=T, sep=",")
funData= subset(myData, units="ft3(monthly total)", select=units:value)    
write.csv(funData, file="funData.csv")
```

To a program in Shell Script, I tried:

```
pwd
cd /Users/yourusername/Desktop
touch RunThisProgram
nano RunThisProgram
(((In nano, I wrote))) 
if
grep -r yourFileName.csv ft3(monthly total)
cat > funData.csv
else 
cat > nofun.csv
fi
control+x (((used control x to close nano)))

chmod -x RunThisProgram
./RunThisProgram
```

(((It runs for a while)))

We get a funData.csv file output but that file is empty

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, right now we do not have your data. Please provide us with a small sample which reproduces the issue.

Comment: I don't understand the requests, are you asking what the data in a .csv file would look like?

Comment: just FYI, there doesn't seem to be any reason you can't run R on the unix system that you have access to, if that's your preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't actually running, because there are a couple problems with your script.

1. `grep` needs the pattern first, and quoted; `-r` is for recursing a
   directory...
2. `if` without a `then`
3. `cat` is called wrong so it is actually reading from stdin.

You really only need one line:

```
grep -F "ft3(monthly total)" yourFileName.csv > funData.csv
```